# strtok not working if extracting string is from fgets

Tags: c, strtok

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char string[100];
   printf("this will be an exercise to test how to use strtok\n");
   printf("Please enter a text with spaces");
   printf("\n");
   while ((getchar()) != '\n');
   fgets(string,100,stdin);
   // Extract the first token
   char * token = strtok(string, " ");
   // loop through the string to extract all other tokens
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token ); //printing each token
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
   return 0;
```

I'm learning about strtok and have encountered a problem where if the words are defined in the string[] array the strtok works fine, and it prints out individually each word that is separated by the space. However, if I add fgets to retrieve the input from the user, the program just stops there. I suspect it is because of the fgets, but I'm not sure what the proper fix should be. Any help would be nice thanks.

Comment: What's this line for? `while ((getchar()) != '\n');` What exactly are you typing? Is it possible that whatever you typed was eaten by the while loop and then `fgets` is waiting for you to type something? https://ideone.com/b4UMAi

Comment: its suppose to get rid of the \n before the fgets starts reading the input

Comment: The function of `fgets` is to stop the execution of the code to await user input, in this case via the command line or predefined GUI. The `token` variable is being used before it is declared.

Comment: isnt the char * token the declaration of the variable?

Comment: What `\n` do you want to get rid of? There was no input before that could have left it in the buffer. I would guess you just consume your whole input in that line and `fgets` has to wait for a new line from you.

Comment: How would you use a variable before declaring or defining it? Your compiler would tell you. Here, `token` is defined and initialized properly.

Comment: What input do you provide?

Comment: Oh, that `getchar` line is a kludgy hack used to work around the shortcomings of `scanf`, which now has found its way into code that doesn't use `scanf` at all. Remove that line and you should be fine. (If you suspect that `strtok`"doesn't work" it might be a good iea to print the string you got from `fgets` before tokenizing ist.)

Comment: `while ((getchar()) != '\n');` is an infinite loop when `getchar()` returns `EOF` due to end-of-file.  Something possible, even for `stdin`.  Do not use code like this.